# Searching for keyword in multiple columns and rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to macros and trying to edit this code to search an my entire table and not just one column.

```
Sub search()
    Dim key_word As String
    Dim x, n_rows As Integer
    Dim split_list As Variant



Rows("15:200").EntireRow.Hidden = False
key_word = Range("I7").Value
n_rows = Range("A15", Range("A15").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Rows("15:200").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    
Range("I15").Select
    For x = 1 To n_rows
    split_list = Split(ActiveCell, " ")
    For i = 0 To UBound(split_list)
        If split_list(i) = key_word Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.AutoFit
        End If
    Next
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next
End Sub
```

Code currently works for one column. I have tried tweaking it to - Range("A15:N15").Select, but this doesn't work. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Just use `Range.Find` with `LookAt:= xlPart`. If you can have multiple matches then use `AutoFilter` instead with wildcard search

Comment: Do you want to hide the row when something is found? If so, I also suggest you use a `Union` to avoid repeating operations

Comment: Exactly, i want to hide the row when something is found.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Range.AutoFilter` to isolate the rows of interest by using a wildcard search

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- Update sheet

ws.Range("A15:N15").AutoFilter Field:=ws.Range("I:I").Column, Criteria1:="*" & ws.Range("I7") & "*"
```

From there you can work with the `SpecialCells (xlCellTypeVisible)` to hide rows

Comment: Thanks for the help!